# Logrotate.service failed - syslog and boot.log not getting populated - Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, syslog

Got a new server and installed Ubuntu server 20.04 on it yesterday.  Everything was working properly yesterday.  Shutdown the server in the night and started it today.

Found out syslog and boot.log were empty.

```
systemctl list-units --state=failed
  UNIT              LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION     
● logrotate.service loaded failed failed Rotate log files

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed.
```

Checked the status of logrotate.service.

```
systemctl status logrotate.service
● logrotate.service - Rotate log files
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-06-03 15:14:08 IST; 20min ago
TriggeredBy: ● logrotate.timer
       Docs: man:logrotate(8)
             man:logrotate.conf(5)
    Process: 1070 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1070 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions.
```

Checked the logrotate.conf file

```
cat logrotate.conf
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# use the adm group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root adm

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
#dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

Restarted the logrotate.service

```
    systemctl restart logrotate.service
systemctl status logrotate              
● logrotate.service - Rotate log files
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2021-06-03 16:02:57 IST; 47s ago
TriggeredBy: ● logrotate.timer
       Docs: man:logrotate(8)
             man:logrotate.conf(5)
    Process: 16162 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 16162 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

This is the logrotate.service

```
systemctl cat logrotate.service         
# /lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service
[Unit]
Description=Rotate log files
Documentation=man:logrotate(8) man:logrotate.conf(5)
ConditionACPower=true

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf

# performance options
Nice=19
IOSchedulingClass=best-effort
IOSchedulingPriority=7

# hardening options
#  details: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html
#  no ProtectHome for userdir logs
#  no PrivateNetwork for mail deliviery
#  no ProtectKernelTunables for working SELinux with systemd older than 235
#  no MemoryDenyWriteExecute for gzip on i686
PrivateDevices=true
PrivateTmp=true
ProtectControlGroups=true
ProtectKernelModules=true
ProtectSystem=full
RestrictRealtime=true
```

But still the syslog and boot.log are empty.

Any help regarding this will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`logrotate -d` told me, that the condition for the trigger were not fulfilled.
`systemctl status logrotate` gave me the reason why. It was `ConditionACPower=true` in `/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service`
After changing to `ConditionACPower=false` and restarting service
`systemctl status logrotate` shows:

```
○ logrotate.service - Rotate log files
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ● logrotate.timer
       Docs: man:logrotate(8)
             man:logrotate.conf(5)
```

Although the status is `inactive (dead)`, logrotate works now.

Comment: I appears you are answering some other question not the one here.

Answer (score -1):

In your `logrotate.conf`, the "`su root adm`" line is wrong.

Read `man logrotate.conf` and change the line to "`adm`". It is a group name, not a command.

Comment: why should some default value be changed?

Comment: This is not correct. From [`logrotate(8)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/logrotate.8.html): **su user group** Rotate log files set under this user and group instead of using default user/group (usually root). *user* specifies the user name used for rotation and *group* specifies the group used for rotation. If the  user/group you specify here does not have sufficient privilege to make files with the ownership you've specified in a *create* instruction, it will cause an error.